# Rails 4 + PostgreSQL hstore, can't execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rvm, pg, hstore

I have RubyOnRails 4.1.4 and PostgreSQL installed on my MacOS X by:

```
brew install postgresql
```

When I'm trying to migrate this one:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore
```

It gives out me an error:

```
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
```

I tried to find "hstore.control" in filesystem using:

```
find / -name "hstore.control"
```

And found out that this file is located in the different path:

```
usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/share/postgresql/extension/hstore.control
```

So how can I redefine "PG" gem's configuration to correct the path of the hstore extension?
I just tried to remove the gem and install it with:

```
rvm all do gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/bin/pg_config
```

But it didn't work. I still have the same error.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I just created symlink to correct path, but anyway it gives me out the same error.

Comment: Didn't install the contrib modules?

Comment: @CraigRinger Contrib modules installing by default. I found hstore.control in my filesystem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I just created a symlink, reinstalled gem `pg`, and now all works fine.

Comment: whats the export variable in your symlink ? I have the same problem

Comment: @RonakJain you just need to create a symlink of actual location of `hstore.control` in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/`

Comment: can you please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 28):

The solution is simple, just install postgresql-contrib in your OS and then run the migration as it is shown here [Rails 4 PostgreSQL integration](http://yousefourabi.com/blog/2014/03/rails-postgresql/) or any other way you using.
For example if you are using ubuntu it will be:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-X.X
```

where X.X is the postgresql version that you are using. If it is version 9.3 it be:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

I also think for MAC Os is almost same, only that you will use brew.

Comment: Yes, it's worked for after installing postgresql-contrib-9.3

Comment: this answer saved my life, was having this exact error and I didn't even think of using the contrib version instead of the standard one. eg: Migrations (and all rake commands) failed with postgres-9.4 installed but everything worked when I purged that and installed postgres-contrib-9.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This link helped me out. We need to install postgresql-contrib before trying to create a HStore extension.

https://gist.github.com/terryjray/3296171